# Pass variable content to dynamic block verbatim in Terraform, or multiple dynamic sub blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

Im trying to update my terraform proxmox module accoring to new disk formatting e.g.

https://github.com/TheGameProfi/terraform-provider-proxmox/blob/master/docs/resources/vm_qemu.md#disks-block

Edit: Original repository is this one https://github.com/Telmate/terraform-provider-proxmox - but original repo owners seem not to care anymore, so thus this fork was created. But the disks structure was intented to be this way unfortunaly even in original repo.

```
  disks {
    ide {
      //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
    }
    sata {
      //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
    }
    scsi {
      //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
    }
    virtio {
      //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
    }
  }
}
```

There can be virtio {virtio1,2,3,4...n}, scsi, ide.

What I tought I could do is to create variable like this in moule instance, and pass it to  disk block e.g. the resource.

```
  vm_disk = {
    virtio = {
      virtio0 = {
        disk = {
          storage  = "lvm"
          size     = "30G"
          discard  = "on"
          iothread = 1
    }
      }
      virtio1 = {
        disk = {
          storage  = "lvm"
          size     = "150G"
          discard  = "on"
          iothread = 1
    }
      }
  
    }
  }
```

But boy, was I wrong. I've tried and tried (trial and error at this stage really)

I don't need to do any value sanitation, I don't care - I just need to pass the structure from variable to dynamic block inside of the module. I dont care if there is size, storage etc. defined if it would be too difficult

This is my latest creation and of course its not working at all and Im quite out of ideas.

```
  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = var.vm_disk
    iterator = item
    content {
      dynamic "virtio" {
        for_each = item.value.virtio != null ? [item.value.virtio] : []
        content {
          disk = virtio.value
        }
      }
      dynamic "scsi" {
        for_each = item.value.scsi != null ? [item.value.scsi] : []
        content {
          disk = scsi.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is variable deffinition:

```
variable "vm_disk" {
  description = "A disk block used to configure the disk devices"
  type        = map(any)
  default     = {}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT2:

The final structure should look like this, but nothing I've tried seems to work:

```
  disks {
    ide {
      ide0 {
        disk {
          //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
        }
      }
      ide1 {
        disk {
          //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
        }
      }
    }
    //<arguments omitted for brevity...>
  }
}
```

Comment: Due to how this provider is designed -- using nested blocks to enforce a rigid configuration structure -- there is no alternative to writing out the arguments in each block manually. A dynamic assignment of the entire structure would be possible only if the provider's schema were designed to allow that, by treating the entire "disks" structure as a single argument of an object type.

Comment: I absolutely agree on that part. Well, its a fork of more known repository - I provided link to original repo. In my opinion this kind of structure is absolutely horrible, I absolutely hate it ...but Im just a user, not a programmer. Anyway, if you have anything in mind, how to overcome this - I would be really grateful. I dont insist on beaing able to copy the structure 1:1. Im still trying to come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

The goal you've described suggests a map of objects, and so you should write out the object types you actually intend to use so that Terraform can give you better feedback when things aren't working:

```
variable "vm_disk" {
  type = map(object({
    ide = optional(object({
      # (whatever attributes are needed for ide disks)
    }))
    sata = optional(object({
      # (whatever attributes are needed for sata disks)
    }))
    scsi = optional(object({
      # (whatever attributes are needed for scsi disks)
    }))
    virtio = optional(object({
      # (whatever attributes are needed for virtio disks)
    }))
  }))
}
```

With the above type constraint, Terraform will ensure that each of these attributes is either an object or `null`, and that if it's an object then it has all of the attributes required for that nested object type.

You can then exploit this "definitely an object or null" guarantee to use the splat operator `[*]` in its [Single Values as Lists](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat#single-values-as-lists) variation, to simplify your `for_each` expressions:

```
  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = var.vm_disk
    iterator = item
    content {
      dynamic "ide" {
        for_each = item.value.ide[*]
        content {
          disk {
            # ... argument assignments from ide.value
          }
        }
      }
      dynamic "sata" {
        for_each = item.value.sata[*]
        content {
          disk {
            # ... argument assignments from sata.value
          }
        }
      }
      dynamic "scsi" {
        for_each = item.value.scsi[*]
        content {
          disk {
            # ... argument assignments from scsi.value
          }
        }
      }
      dynamic "virtio" {
        for_each = item.value.virtio[*]
        content {
          disk {
            # ... argument assignments from virtio.value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

An expression like `item.value.ide[*]`, when `item.value.ide` is not of a sequence-like type, evaluates to a single-element list when `item.value.ide` is not null, or to an empty list when it is null. This is therefore a shorthand for `item.value.ide != null ? [item.value.ide] : []`.

Because this provider is designed to use nested blocks for these structures, there is no alternative to writing out each argument individually. Providers designed in this way rely on Terraform to guarantee that the data structure is valid per the schema, which means that Terraform must statically verify the structure during the validation step.

For example, if you want to expose the `format` argument associated with IDE disks then you'd first declare that as part of the object type for the `ide` attribute:

```
    # ...
    ide = optional(object({
      format = optional(string)
    }))
    # ...
```

Then assign that attribute to the corresponding argument inside the configuration block:

```
      dynamic "ide" {
        for_each = item.value.ide[*]
        content {
          disk {
            format = ide.value.format
          }
        }
      }
```

Because this provider is not designed to take the entire configuration as a single argument with a data structure assigned to it, there is no alternative but to write out the rules for generating dynamic blocks with explicit arguments inside. If your module is not going to simplify this data structure in any way relative to the underlying provider, it's likely more productive to skip the module and have the caller declare a `resource` block directly with the needed settings, thus avoiding all of the complexity of dynamically generating configuration blocks.

Comment: Hi, that you very much for you time!  Now Im expriencing different error, but I think Im much closer. 
Do I understand correctly, that I must have also virtio0,virtio1..n (scsi0 etc.) defined in nested block in variable definition?

Comment: After several hours, another failure on my end :(. I cant wrap my head around it, as Im not able to achieve correct strucutre. I've edited the question to include desired format.

If you could help me with this one even more, I will be really grateful.

Comment: I understood your `virtio0`, `virtio1`, etc as arbitrary map keys decided by the caller of the module, which I represented by defining the input variable as a map of an object type. When the caller of the module assigns a value to this variable they'd need to choose a set of map keys to use, and those would be available in these blocks as `item.key` (similar to `item.value` but for the _keys_ from the map, rather than the values) if you want to use those keys as part of the definition somewhere.